# Play Framework 2.4.x is it possible to import routes files or otherwise generate them in fragments or programmatically?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

It appears as if a single route file is the only option under Play.

Does that prevent any form of auto-management of routes for modules?

Could routes be generated some other way other than the route file itself?

Is it likely that the new push towards @Injection techniques make a difference to this in a future release?

What options does a developer have for managing large collections of routes -- some of which are module dependant?

Comment: James Roper indicates this is possible -- if I make any progress I'll advise accordingly. https://jazzy.id.au/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html